# Powershell if foreach(

Tags: powershell, if-statement, foreach

I have to find in a quite large file all lines which content more then 4 **;**

For example this file

```
Text1;Text2;Text3;Text4;Text5;
Text1;Text2;Text3;Text4;Text5;
Text1;Text2;Text3;Text4;Text5;
Text1;Text2;Text3;Text4;Text5;
Text1;Text2;Text3
Text1;Text2;Text3;Text4;Text5;
Text1;Text2;Text3
Text1;Text2;Text3;Text4;Text5;
```

Counting the lines is no problem

```
$content=Get-Content .\sample.txt
[regex]::matches($content,";").count
```

gives me 34 hits.

Counting the desired chars per line also no problem

```
$content=Get-Content .\sample.txt
foreach ($lines in $content) {[regex]::matches($lines,";").count}
```

Gives

- 5
- 5
- 5
- 5
- 2
- 5
- 2
- 5

Now I would like to get all lines where I have less then 4 ;

I tried this:

```
if (foreach ($lines in $content) {[regex]::matches($lines,";").count} -le 3) {Write-Host $lines}
```

But this gives me an error.

With this

```
$count=foreach ($lines in $content) {[regex]::matches($lines,";").count}
if ($count -le 3) {Write-Host $lines}
```

I get one line - the final matching line, but not the other.

How to combine foreach and if?

Comment: `Get-Content .\sample.txt | ? {[regex]::matches($_,";").count -le 3}`

Answer (score 2):

A more PowerShell-idiomatic way to solve this would be to use the `Where-Object` filter cmdlet:

```
$Lines = Get-Content .\sample.txt |Where-Object { [regex]::Matches($_,';').Count -le 3 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong with this code:

```
if (foreach ($lines in $content) {[regex]::matches($lines,";").count} -le 3) {Write-Host $lines}
```

You dont put `foreach` inside an `if` statement's condition parenthesis. Use the `if` statement inside the `foreach` instead like this:

```
$content=Get-Content .\sample.txt
foreach ($lines in $content) {
    $semiCols = [regex]::matches($lines,";").count
    if($semiCols -le 3) {
        Write-Host $semiCols
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
PS E:\Programming\PowerShell> .\lines-fetch.ps1
2
2
PS E:\Programming\PowerShell>
```

Comment: Well, you can put statements in places where an expression is expected by wrapping it in `$(...)`

Comment: @Joey I'm not that much into PoweShell scripting, but as you say, the statement has to be wrapped inside `$(...)`, which OP is not using in his example. And again, see this specific example the OP has here. If you wrap the `foreach` statement inside `$(...)`, what will you get? Is this `if ($(foreach ($lines in $content) {[regex]::matches($lines,";").count}) -le 3) {...}` a way to evaluate and check each line? I don't think it will work and evaluate the `if` condition for each line loop, but the whole wrapped result as a whole.

Comment: Agreed, it's hard to see what they were actually trying there and chances are it's simply bogus. But you can turn statements into expressions by wrapping them into a subexpression with `$(...)`, and I wanted to point that out. I usually use it to get a bunch of statements as the first part of a pipeline, but I'm sure there are weirder use cases out there for it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
PS D:\test> (sls -n '(.*;){4}' sample.txt).line
Text1;Text2;Text3
Text1;Text2;Text3

# or in long form:
PS D:\test> Select-String -NotMatch -Pattern '(.*;){4}' -Path .\sample.txt | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line
```

The regex matches at least 4 semicolons with anything between them. -NotMatch gets the lines that don't match that regex - i.e. less than 4 semicolons.